# gridview System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, error-handling, vb.net-2010

i receive the error when my web app is published. when i run the app it works fine.

im using vs 2010

this is the line of code where it errors:

```
  Dim money As String = footer.Cells(1).Text.Replace("£", String.Empty)
```

the aim is to have a look in the footer on the gridview and then remove the £ sign so that it no longer exist

i rowdatabound the information from an excel spreadsheet to the girdview

```
Protected Sub GridView5_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As  System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView5.RowDataBound
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Footer Then
        e.Row.Cells(0).Text = "Total"
        e.Row.Cells(1).Text = total.ToString("c")
    End If


End Sub
```

can anyone help please

Comment: Show the GridView markup too

Answer (score 0):

In this line here:

```
e.Row.Cells(1).Text = total.ToString("c")
```

Where is `total` initialised?

If it isn't initialised, then when you come to access it via Cells(1) here:

```
Dim money As String = footer.Cells(1).Text.Replace("£", String.Empty)
```

You will get the NullReferenceException